# It is possible to find out the final stream url of an m3u file?

Tags: stream, m3u8, m3u

It is possible to find out the final stream url of an m3u file.
E.g. m3u file url is http://server.address:8000/544.m3u and this url is streaming from e.g. https://youtuxxx.com/trgghh.m3u

Foolowing redirects